# Masses of all the particles in the Standard Theory

Tags: energy, standard-model, mass, higgs, equivalence-principle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum)

I'm sure this question has been asked here before but I wasn't able to find it clearly answered in one q/a session. I'm a newb, yes.

In the standard model (which I understand is well experimentally supported except for the absent Higgs Boson), all the elementary particles must carry some mass, correct?

For E=MC2 to be true, you can't have energy without mass. And energy has been carried away in collisions of sub-atomic particles that can't be accounted for (the Higgs). So EVERY elementary particle in the Standard Model must have mass, correct?

Comment: Particles without mass (e.g photons) do have energy.

Comment: As with your other question, there are several questions on this site that cover the topic already; the linked one is only one of them.