# The electron jumps and lets loose photons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons

Where is the source of the photon.

If the photon propagates from within the electrons transit does this point to some sort of field?

Does the energy come from a boundary being broken in laymens terms a sound barrier type effect the electron performs on its shell as it changes orbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [photon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon) is just a quantum of light or transporter of electromagnetic radiation. Whenever an electromagnetic wave is radiated, it is transmitted in the form of photons. Thus when an electron jumps from one energy level to another, the difference between energies of the two energy levels between which the transition of electron takes place is radiated in the form of a high-energy photon. One thing must be understood that photon neither propagates through electrons, nor is emitted by electrons. Hence, electrons do not let loose photons. They just radiate energy which gets transmitted in the form of photons

Comment: Does this energy packet take mass when it is radiated?

Comment: Photons have zero rest mass... But, they have momentum at such high relativistic speeds (I mean, c). Due to this reason, photons are supposed to have mass and from photo-electric effect, it was calculated to be $1.8*10^{-45} kg$. Also, regarding [Space time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time), they have mass and hence they're affected by gravity...

Comment: You could also refer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum