# Solar Sail Questions

Tags: kinematics, photons, momentum, reflection

I'm just looking for a good (better) analogy.

How do massless photons put *pressure* on a surface especially when it's a mirror? Using the analogy of the wind (atmosphere) on a sail breaks down when I think that an air sail *catches* the wind and that the wind has mass and is an *object* in motion but how can a mirror *catch* a proton and how would it matter if it does if it's massless? Where does the force come from? The one article that mentions red shift was a math equation so it did not help me get my brain around it.

Does it have more to do with the momentum energy of the proton and can that be explained in simple terms?

As a child I imagined a solar wind sail but a light sail is a different concept.

I hope it's not too dumb of a question and that this type of question is appropriate here.

Comment: The core of the question is answered in http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum, and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57442/how-does-the-solar-sailing-concept-work is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is newton second law:
$$
\mathbf F = \frac{\Delta\mathbf p}{\Delta t}
$$

As you can see, its variation of momentum that brings force. So, its the transfer of momentum. Granted, photons are massless, but they do have momentum.

There are two ways of a photon transfer momentum to a solar sail: The photon is absorbed (also heats up the sail), or, the photon is reflected.

Comment: Thanks, I imagined that some photons were absorbed (by chance?) and that that would be converted to heat but how is that energy potential then converted into the *work* of moving the sail? Is it by being re-emited?

Comment: @JohnH There is a rate of absorption/reflection depending on the EM properties of the sail. Its easily calculable using EM Theory. And about the second question, its a fully inelastic collision. The sail will gain the momentum of incoming photon, and have a definite speed. The the sail will move because of it. Conservation of energy tells: Energy of photon = Kinetic energy of sail (from the speed derived earlier) + heating of sail. If you want I can insert all those relations in my answer =).

Comment: Isn't there also a lot force on the sail by all the electrons and protons of the solar wind plasma?

Comment: @ Physicist137, Is this article on **Resolution of the Abraham-Minkowski Controversy** old news? https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1208/1208.0872.pdf

Comment: @JohnH In a real scenario of a sail in solar system, yes. You have to take into consideration solar wind. About the article, well, I have no idea. Apparently has it has no date... (how odd..).

Comment: Feynman says light is not truly reflected but absorbed and re-emitted. So if some are not re-emitted instantly but after the sail heats up are perhaps emitted as inferred(?) with it's longer wavelength . . . . In the RAMC article I posted above, it's the light passing *through* the medium that pushes it and not by "reflection" or absorption. It was published in 2010. It was way over my head but I got that much out of it. And I did not see that addressed in any other articled posted here on this subject. But with a solar wind wouldn't it be hard to test or is it an exact science?

Comment: @ Physicist137 Unless I seriously misunderstood the article.

Comment: @JohnH Well..I haven't read the article. But, whatever is the model you use: light passing through the medium, light reflecting, light magically vanishing and transforming in heat (absorption), It does not matter: The momentum will be conserved, and so as energy. So you can disregard how exactly the process happens, and come up with a crude model, of light as a ball hitting sail, and getting reflected (elastic collision) or absorbed (innelastic collision), and then apply conservation of momentum and energy to figure out what will happen to the sail (speed and heating). And that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Most people believe that you need mass to transmit a force, or even to be able make one, but the more fundamental concept happens not the force but the momentum. The momentum is the capacity to interact with another entity and transfer it some change in speed. 
In the case of the photon, it is massless but however has momentum and energy. 
The energy and momentum of a photon depend only on its frequency ($\nu$) or inversely, its  wavelength  ($\lambda$):

$E=\hbar\omega=h\nu=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$

$\boldsymbol{p}=\hbar\boldsymbol{k}$

Comment: Yes, I imagine most people don't even understand what *mass* is which is why we explain everything by analogy (except for mathematicians) ;)

Comment: Newton couldn't have known better... cut him some slack. :-)