# If photons don't have mass, how can they accelerate objects?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, momentum

As far as I know photons don't have mass but they do have momentum ($p=mv$). Scientists say that if we put a shiny (reflective) shield of large radius in the vacuum of space, then light from sun will will start moving the shield. How can these two facts be commensurate?

Comment: okay got it! it doesnt have nothing to do with momentum the electric charges that forms light make it sail..

Comment: It does have everything to do with momentum. Light does not have charge or mass, but it does have momentum. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Physical_properties

Comment: It comes down to them having momentum, which brings us to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/