# Why would a photon striking an electron "make both recoil"?

Tags: photons, momentum, electrons

Why would a photon striking an electron "make both recoil" as I read in an answer to another question. If the photon is massless, how can it make an electron change momentum?

Comment: $\uparrow$ what other question/answer?

Comment: Related (possible/partial dupe): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116464/

Comment: possible duplicate of [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/)

Answer (score 3):

> If the photon is massless, how can it make an electron change
>   momentum?

Because, relativistically, [momentum isn't proportional to (invariant) mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Invariant_mass)?

Thus, [particles with zero invariant mass can have non-zero momentum.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum)