# How to get the accurate relativistic momentum form for photons?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, momentum

I have studied from Griffiths, the relativistic form of momentum is
$$p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} m_0v$$

Now when I evaluate the momentum for photon, I just insert $v=c$ and $m_0=0$ and I get $p= 0/0$. How does it make sense?

Can you tell me that where I am wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/)

Comment: You have to take the double limit $m \to 0$ *and* $v \to 1$ (I'm using $c=1$ units), don't simply set $m = 0$ and $v = 1$.  You know how the the mass $m$ is bound to energy and momentum from the [energy-momentum relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation).  So, in $p = mv/\sqrt{1 - v^2}$ replace $m$ by $\sqrt{E^2 - p^2}$ and let $v$ be $1$, in this way you will recover $p = E$, but starting from energy-momentum relation and setting $m = 0$ is much simpler.

Comment: can you plz explain without setting c=1. from the equation $\vec{p}=\frac{m \vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$  to E =pc  please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider a particle with some finite energy $E$ and use that constraint to take the $v\rightarrow c$ limit.

With Lorentz factor $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$, the relativistic total energy is $E = \gamma mc^2$. Therefore, $p/E = v/c^2$. With the particular case of $v = c$, it follows that $E = pc$.

Although really, you should simply consider $E = pc$ for massless particles to be more fundamental. The general relation is $(mc^2)^2 = E^2 - (pc)^2$, which corresponds to the the norm-squared of the four-momentum vector in relativity.

Comment: I understand how to get this form, but $p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} mv$ is it not valid for photon momentum ? why not?

Comment: @zero_field: it's not valid because photons have zero mass and $0/0$ doesn't mean anything. However, having the constraint of some particular energy enables you to take the limit in a way that gets the correct result--with the numerator and denominator changing in a consistent way.

Comment: I have found that form in Griffiths, so why cant i use that for photon?

Comment: @zero_field: You have just discovered why yourself in the question you asked. Why is is the fact that it is found in Griffiths relevant? Which Griffiths, anyway? (If it's *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, then he discusses just this issue for photons in section 10.2.3 in the 1981 ed.--sorry, I don't have the newer one on-hand right now.)

Comment: Yes it is Introduction to Electrodynamics, page no 509 and the topic is, relativistic energy and momentum.

Comment: @zero_field: My edition doesn't have a p. 509, sorry. But I suggest you look up "photon" in the index. The section I referred to above is labeled "relativistic kinematics" in my edition. $v = pc^2/E$ is also derived in that section in my edition.