# Derivation of $E=pc$ for a massless particle?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, momentum

In classical mechanics, massless particles don't exist because for $m=0$, $p=0$.

The relativistic relation between energy, mass and spatial momentum is: $E^2= (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$ . So it is said that setting $m=0$ in the first equation you get $E=pc$.

How could setting $m=0$ in that equation give you $E=pc$ whilst $p$ appears in the equation and we know $p=γmu$? If you set $m=0$ you will have **indeterminacy due to "$γm$"**. It seems to me like we are doing a "trick" in order to get the $E=pc$. Perhaps there is another proof for this relation?

Comment: Why not start with Maxwell's equations and a plane wave?

Comment: $p=\gamma m u$ holds for massive particles only

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/2451 and links therein.

Comment: In particular, in the question cited by @Qmechanic see [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13288/5739).

Comment: @Qmechanic it's closely related, of course, but this seems to be asking about a specific conceptual issue with the definitions of the relevant concepts. I don't think it's a duplicate of #2229. It may be a duplicate of [#119490](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119490) but even then, I see it as sufficiently different.

Comment: @garyp Yes, that's exactly what I was looking at. Still, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Probably closer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116464/

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the equation
$$
E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4
$$
is derived from the relations
$$
\begin{align}
E = \gamma mc^2,\qquad p = \gamma m v. \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
p = E\frac{v}{c^2}.\tag{2}
$$
Although (1) is only defined for massive particles, it turns out that (2) remains valid when $v=c$, i.e. for massless particles. Indeed, we get
$$
E= pc,
$$
which is consistent with electromagnetism and quantum physics.

Comment: So you don't derive E=pc from the first relation, but from (2), which indeed deribes from (1). The question is how is it possible to derive it from the first equation.

Comment: @NickyR Equation 1 is wrong in the sense that it is a special case. Equation 2 is correct and so is Equation 0. Asking how to derive a correct equation from a wrong one is not a good question. From 1 you can get 0 which is more general, and 0 is actually correct, unlike 1 which only holds sometimes. And 0 has a geometrical meaning that the energy momentum vector has a length of m. To get velocity you can note the energy momentum vector points in the direction tangent to the worldline. Or define $p=\sqrt{E^2/c^2-m^2c^2}$ as the more general definition for p instead of the wrong one (1).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of momentum isn't $\gamma m \dot x$. The proper definition of momentum is that it is the generator of translations. Then you find that for massive representations of the Lorentz group (~timelike curves), $p = m \gamma \dot x$, while for massless representations (~lightlike curves), $p$ is arbitrary, as long as $E = pc$.

Another way of looking at it is that for particles moving on timelike curves, the derivative with respect to *proper time* is a covariant quantity, because *proper time* is invariant. But for lightlike curves, there is no proper time. There are *affine parameters* that are analogous but there are infinitely many of them and none is privileged, so this doesn't give a unique definition of momentum.

Comment: I'm confused: definition of momentum as generator of translations appears, to my knowledge, in quantum mechanics. Is there a way to describe the same thing using only special relativity? without waves?

Comment: The concept of generator of translations applies also to classical mechanics in the Hamiltonian formulation. The difference is that classically the generator is a vector field, whereas the quantum generator is an operator. But they are analogous because vector fields and operators are both Lie algebras.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? or point to places where to read about it? I have some trouble finding it.

Comment: @fffred I think the analogy is somewhat a "deep" insight that you get after much reading from several sources, but I would recommend Armold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, because he talks a lot about the Lie algebra structure in Hamiltonian mechanics.

Comment: Consider Hamiltonian mechanics in canonical coordinates $(x,p)$. Then translations map $(x,p) \mapsto (x+a,p)$. Clearly the vector field that generates this is $\partial/\partial q$. But in canonical coordinates the symplectic form is $dq\wedge dp$, so $\partial/\partial q \mapsto dp$. Thus while it's strictly speaking $\partial/\partial q$ that is the generator of translations, we can associate it with the coordinate p in this way.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer more than once. Too many leave undergrad without a good understanding of Noether's theorem and related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The relation (setting $c = 1$)
$$
E^2 = m^2 + p^2
$$
is more fundamental than $E = \gamma m c^2$ and $p = \gamma m v$.

The former arises naturally as a primary constraint from varying the action
$$
S = -m \int \sqrt{\dot{x}^\mu \eta_{\mu \nu} \dot{x}^\nu} \, d\lambda
$$
The latter expressions only arise when you choose the parametrization $\lambda = t$.

Answer (score 0):

If one considers that the deBroglie relationship holds for photons we have $$p=\frac{h}{\lambda} = \frac{hf}{c} = \frac{E}{c}$$
which immediately gives us $$E=pc.$$

This is consistent with the Lorentz invariant energy four-vector magnitude which yields  the mass of a particle: $$ mc^2=\sqrt{E^2-(pc)^2}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For all particles, $p^{\mu}=(E,\vec{p})$ and $p^{\mu}p_{\mu}\equiv m^2$ (using the mostly-minus metric). Thus $E=\pm \sqrt{m^2+|\vec p|^2}$. If you set $m^2=0$, you get $E=\pm |\vec p|$. The non-trivial aspect of these definitions is that $E$ is to be literally identified as the energy, and $\vec p$ as the spatial momentum (so in the classical limit $E=p^2/2m + \textrm{const.}$ ).

For massive particles with positive-energy ($m^2>0$, $E>0$), the 4-momentum and 4-velocity are related by the equation

$$p^{\mu}=m\,u^{\mu}$$

whereas for massless particles with positive-energy ($m^2=0$, $E>0$), the relationship between the 4-momentum and 4-velocity is given by:

$$p^{\mu}=E\,u^{\mu}$$

where $u^{\mu}$ is a light-cone vector.