# Massless particle that have momentum not equal to 0

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum

I saw some problems in special relativity that use conservation of total energy and momentum and the conclusions are spectacular. My problem is the following: how can a massless particle like neutrino have mementum not equal to 0? If their rest mass is 0 then the momentum $$p = \frac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ should be also 0.

Comment: Similar: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum

Comment: Yes, I have read that. But where is the mistake in the relation I've written?

Comment: The term on the right is undefined (not zero) when $m_0=0$ because $v=c$ and it becomes $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Neutrinos are not massless. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Mass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That formula for momentum is only true for massive particles.

Here's what is *always* true: A particle with a mass $m$ ($\geq 0$) can have an arbitrary  momentum $p$ (in some direction, with magnitude $\geq 0$). The energy of such a particle is

$$ E = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2c^2}$$

The velocity of a particle is equal to

$$
v = \frac{pc^2}{E}
$$

When $m = 0$, $E = pc$ and so $v=c$ -- the particle must travel at the speed of light. For $m \neq 0$, you can solve this for $p$ and find that

$$
p = \gamma m v
$$

where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$.

Comment: Ok. The relation between E and p can be proved without using relation? $$p = \frac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ All the proofs I've seen so far use this.

Comment: To be more precise, your equation is a result rather than the principle. $E=\sqrt{m^2c^4 + p^2 c^2}$ is a result of combining energy and momentum into a four vector $p^\mu =(E/c, \vec{p})$ and then defining its invariant norm to be $mc$, which is the only dimensionally reasonable guess. This has higher logical precedence in SR than $p=m_0 v/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$

Comment: Is there an absolutely true relation between momentum and velocity, without involving energy? If a particle has zero speed, then it must have no momentum?

Comment: @SebiSebi That's just a change in syntax. Take the equation I gave you for $E$ and plug it in: $$v = \frac{pc^2}{\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}}.$$ Now, the issue is just that this equation has to be solved for $p$ in terms of $v$, but that when $m=0$, there is no solution for $p$ in terms of $v$ (because $v=c$ is a constant). So, when $m = 0$, $p$ is entirely unrelated to $v$. There certainly is a momentum $p$ (which is a *more* fundamental quantity than velocity); it's just that for massless particles, speed is not an indication of momentum.