# 4-momentum of photon

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum

The 4-momentum is defined as $p=mU$ where m is the rest mass of the particle and $U$ is the 4-velocity. Now I am confused as to how this applies to a photon for which one can't define $U$ since there can be no rest frame for a photon. I'm trying to see why **$p$ is still tangential to it's world line in any frame**. I want to arrive at the conclusion that $p$ is a null vector. So I am not looking for an explanation which uses that equation $E^2 = (m c^2)^2 + p^2 c^2 $in first place(or that photons have $zero$ rest mass). I want see how it follows from that fact that photon travels at speed $c$. Just like how we use this fact to conclude that 4-position vector is a null vector. By null vector I mean whose magnitude vanishes under Lorentz metric. This is not homework. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I have already gone through [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/) and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, my question has to do with null vectors and the definitions of 4-velocity and 4-momentum.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because the photon definitely has energy, it must have a four-momentum vector, but it must be defined differently from m**U** because the proper time, $\tau$, along its worldline is zero. 
$$d\tau= dt\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$$
 The photon four-momentum vector is *defined* to be $$\textbf{p}=\left[\matrix{p^t\\p^x\\p^y\\p^z}\right]=\left[\matrix{E/c\\Ev_x/c^2\\Ev_y/c^2\\Ev_z/c^2}\right],$$ with $$v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2=c^2$$

The four-vector scalar product of this will be zero, implying that the mass of the photon is zero because $\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{p}=m^2$ = 0 (within a sign factor depending on your sign convention for the scalar product).

Answer (score 2):

let speed of light c=1(by choosing the right units

We do not neccessarily need the proper time to define the four velocity and hence, the four momentum. **Any scalar λ which is independent of the frame you choose is a appropriate choice to replace the proper time τ.** The reason is that,four vector is nothing but a **tangent vector** of the particle's world line.And we can have a plenty of parameter choices for a curve(world line our case).

One can esily check out that the space component of the four velocity equals the usual veloctiy times its time component.(by chain rule)

As for a photon, we choose the parameter λ so that the tangent vector of its world line is just its four momentum.This can be done simply because four momentum parallels to four velocity.Since the square of a photon's usual velocity always equals to c=1,we get that the Lorentz metric of its momentum is zero.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).