# Decay kinematics of Higgs boson

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, kinematics, higgs

So I'm looking at a two-body decay question for the $h\rightarrow\gamma\gamma$ decay channel for the Higgs Boson. I am asked to find the invariant mass of the Higgs boson.

I'm not too sure how to tackle this question. However, I have started with considering the centre of mass frame for this reaction

$$
s=(E_1+E_2)^2-(p_1+p_2)^2
$$

This gives me,

$$
s=E_1^{2}+E_2^{2}+2E_1E_2-p_1^{2}+p_2^{2}+2p_1p_2
$$

I'm a little confused what to do with this now, all I know is that the mass of the photon is $0$, and that I should probably write out the 4-momenta of the two photons...which I think is this:

$$
p_1=(E_1,E_1\sin{\theta},0,E_1\cos{\theta})
$$ 
$$
p_2=(E_2,-E_2\sin{\theta},0,-E_2\cos{\theta})
$$

Could anyone please advise and help on this one! Thank you...

Comment: You can look at:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186031/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186031/59023) for an answer to your 4-vector question about photons.

Comment: Not relevant to particle physics, but thank you.

Comment: Really?  It's still a null vector (i.e., $\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{p} = 0$) though, so now you've got me curious.  Why is that answer not relevant to particle physics?

Comment: It is relevant but we normally use natural units.

Comment: Oh, I see... So $c = 1$ and all that?  So just change the $E v_{j}/c^{2}$ terms to $p_{j}$ then, which are just $E$ times $\sin{\theta}$ or $\cos{\theta}$.

Comment: I found the following dissertation that has numerical estimates that may be of use/interest:  [http://www.roma1.infn.it/cms/tesiPHD/nourbakhsh.pdf](http://www.roma1.infn.it/cms/tesiPHD/nourbakhsh.pdf).