# Is photon massless?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light

if photon is massless then in E2=m2c4+p2c2 is m=0 ?
and p=mv1-mv2 shouldnt be zero too.
if both the statements are true then does photon has no energy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/)