# Energy of Photons

Tags: photons

Can the energy of a photon be found out by using the most famous equation in all Physics, $E^2=(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$ ?  If yes, then what will be the $p$ there?

Comment: Hi, welcome to PSE. Wherever you find that equation, it should tell you what p represents as well, but maybe ask yourself: why is the p  sometimes included, and sometimes not?

Comment: I know that momentum is denoted by "p" whereas p=mv. If the mass of an object (e.g. photon) is zero, then the E becomes zero too. But the energy of a photon can't be zero. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not reading the equation correctly. It's split between rest mass, (which is always there, at same value) and kinetic energy, which **is** related to momentum. Look up Relativistic on Wikipedia

Comment: Will you please give me a example of finding a photon's energy using that equation?

Comment: Try using: $p=h/\lambda$.   BTW, @user17879 is not correct, the second term does not represent kinetic energy.  $p=mv$ is only *mechanical* momentum.  Momentum takes other forms when fields are involved, namely *field momentum*.  But there is a very nice discussion [in this S.E. answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/2233/5739).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The momentum of a photon is **h/ℷ** where ℷ is the wavelength and h is Planck's constant.  The energy of a photon is **hc/ℷ**.  In the equation you wrote, the rest mass of a photon is zero. Leaving you with E = pc.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is the total energy of the particle, $m$ is mass, $p$ is momentum and $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum. Photons are massless, so $m=0$, therefore the energy of the photon is:
$$E=pc$$

Comment: E=pc=(mv)c assuming m=0, E=(0*v)c=0 . But we all know, E≠0 

Comment: No, momentum is not just $mv$. Momentum is $p=mv\gamma$, where $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ and it is called the Lorentz factor.

Comment: Thank you Arthur for your answer. It was giving me a headache since the last few hours.