# Why does the Heisenberg uncertainty principle refer to momentum rather than velocity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

I've been looking at the [Heisenberg uncertainty relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), and something that sticks out to me is the use of momentum rather than velocity. Shouldn't electrons have the same mass? And if they do, why is momentum used?

Comment: It comes from using Hamiltonian mechanics instead of Lagrangian mechanics. Lagrangian mechanics is unfavored for the tangent bundle has no Poisson bracket nor a Dirac one.

Comment: Simplest answer : the principle applies to any particle, including massless ones.  They have momentum even if they're massless.  Long answer involves some mathematics and you can see it [here](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Uncertainty.htm) and is a mathematical consequence of how momentum, position and the wavefunction are defined in quantum theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the uncertainty principle applies to *all* particles, regardless of their mass (and even for [some massless particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum)). Thus, you *could*, if you insisted, phrase the uncertainty principle for electrons as
$$
\Delta v\,\Delta x\geq \frac12\frac{\hbar}{m_e}
$$
and the uncertainty principle for protons as
$$
\Delta v\,\Delta x\geq \frac12\frac{\hbar}{m_p}
$$
and the uncertainty principle for neutrons as
$$
\Delta v\,\Delta x\geq \frac12\frac{\hbar}{m_m}
$$
and the uncertainty principle for helium atoms as as
$$
\Delta v\,\Delta x\geq \frac12\frac{\hbar}{m_\mathrm{He}}
$$
and so on and on and on, but why would you do that when you can just issue a single principle that applies for all particles,
$$
\Delta p\,\Delta x\geq \frac12\hbar,
$$
and be done with it?

Comment: "*Because the uncertainty principle applies to all particles*" [citation needed]. Massless particles require special-relativity, where $\hat P,\hat X$ may not be well-defined objects.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If there are particles to which the HUP does not apply, I'm happy to learn about it. Otherwise, the choice to reduce special relativity to only a reference is a didactic choice based on the level of OP's question; you're welcome to post a separate answer if you think this oversimplifies crucial aspects that OP would otherwise be able to understand and appreciate.

Comment: My point is that you should not claim that the HUP applies to massless particles unless you have a reference that argues that one can do so. I agree with the spirit of the answer though -- that the HUP is oblivious to the actual value of $m$ (as long as $m>0$). Were you to remove the sentence "*(even if they don't have mass)*", I'd be happy to upvote the answer.

Comment: Fine, here's a rewording for the nitpickers ;-).

Answer (score 3):

The general uncertainty relation takes the form
$$
\Delta A\Delta B\ge \frac{1}{2}\vert\langle [\hat A,\hat B]\rangle\vert\, . \tag{1}
$$
Since it is the commutator $[\hat x,\hat p]=i\hbar$ and constant, this specializes (1) to the usual $\Delta x\Delta p\ge \frac{\hbar}{2}$.

Note that $[\hat x,\hat p]=i\hbar$ is the quantum analogue of the classical Poisson bracket $\{x,p\}$, which involves position and momentum.

Moreover, there are closely related Fourier relations connecting the width of a pulse with the wavenumber: 
$\Delta k\Delta x\sim 1$.  Multiplying by $\hbar$ gives you the uncertainty relation, up to a factor of $1/2$, which appears in the formal, quantum mechanical derivation of (1).