# Why don't protons collapse to a point?

Tags: electromagnetism, quarks, strong-force

If the quarks that make up the proton are point particles, and the forces binding them together is the strong force which is $137$ times stronger than the electromagnetic force (which makes the quarks repel), why don't the protons collapse to a point because the quarks don't have a finite radius?

Comment: The strong force is repulsive over small domains of separation

Comment: Thanks. You should put that as an answer though.

Comment: Also, angular momentum is a thing. For example, in a gravitational system of two point masses, they only collapse to a point if angular momentum is zero.

Comment: There's also the Heisenberg uncertainty relation, which means that any particle confined to a tiny region must have an enormous amount of kinetic energy.

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, for the same reason that [electrons don't crash into the nuclei they “orbit”](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit): because [all massive particles obey the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/369011/8563), of the form
$$
\Delta x\,\Delta p\gtrsim\frac12\hbar,
$$
so that if the quarks' motion collapsed to a point, having $\Delta x$ zero (or very small) would require having infinite (or extremely large) $\Delta p$, and since, as a rough approximation,
$$
\Delta p^2 = ⟨p^2⟩-⟨p⟩^2 = ⟨p^2⟩=T,
$$
the kinetic energy, having large $\Delta p$ requires a lot of energy.

(In addition to that, there's the fact that the strong nuclear force is repulsive at low distances, but that is irrelevant - the uncertainty principle would preclude the collapse even if the strong nuclear force was attractive all the way through, like the Coulomb force on electrons is.)

Comment: I know that the residual strong force is repulsive over short distances but i am actually talking about the fundamental strong force, which isn't repulsive.