# Why does the bending of light not depend on the wavelenght or energy of the photon?

Tags: gravity, visible-light

(First paragraph deleted, according to comments see below,  because erroneously assuming that gravitation is described by Newton's three basic laws of motion.)

Can it be derived from Newtonian laws that the angle of the bending  of a photon's path moving close to earth does not depend on its energy and does not vary according to the wavelength of the photon? Even if all objects underlie one and the same acceleration in speed (termed g) they gain different momentum and energy  when gravity exerts (red-shift, blue-shift). How can it be excluded that this gain of momentum and energy does not translate into differences in angles of inflections (as with Raleigh scattering which is a phenomenon of electro-magnetic, not gravitational field)?

In relativistic physics, there is the principle of equivalence of energy and mass. A photon that has no rest mass but has energy should be accelerated and bent by gravitational force according to its energy thus wavelenght.

However, the formula on the angle of bending and on  the shift of frequency show that both angle of curvature of path and change of wavelength/frequency (redshift/blueshift) do not depend on the energy/wavelength/frequency/relativistic mass of the photon.

Why do mass and  energy "cancel out"? The Newtonian deflection angle is: θ=2GM/rc2.

Related:

["Does 'special relativity + newtonian gravity' predict gravitational bending of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425890/does-special-relativity-newtonian-gravity-predict-gravitational-bending-of-l)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140883/discussion-on-question-by-peter-bernhard-why-does-neither-gravitational-redshift).

Answer (score 2):

**Basics of Newtonian gravitational force**

- Bodies are attracted by gravitational source. If the body initially does not move towards the center of force, its trajectory will be curved.
- A higher initial velocity causes a lower curvature.
- The component of motion perpendicular to the center of force remains constant (in airless space).

**Basics of the constancy of the speed of light**

- All photons move with the same velocity. Thus, they all follow gravitogeodesic paths.

**Basics of Einstein's understanding of gravitation**

- Gravity exerts an attraction on other bodies, but is not a force. On the falling body no acceleration acts (we are always weightless at the free fall in the airless space!, we feel no force).
- The gravitational potential is not only composed of the surrounding masses but is self-amplifying, the larger the surrounding masses are.
- With c, the gravitational potential in the space can be described unambiguously.
- With increasing gravitational potential the speed of light slows down (from an external observer far away from the point of changing gravitational potential).

*To your question about the redshift*

- The geodesic of bodies changes seriously with the changing value of the mass of the central body.
- The geodesic also changes seriously, if the body is in relation to the other gravitational source in the same order of magnitude.
- The geodesic changes - not so seriously - also still because of the self-amplifying gravitational effect. For example, our earth orbit would be more curved in the area of an umpteen times heavier sun than to be expected with the Newtonian formula.
- What has this to do with the redshift of photons? Emitted photons of heavier masses (etalon: our earth) are redshifted.

*To your question about the geodesic of photons of different frequency*

- The gravitational potential between two bodies is self-amplifying (thus not simply additive).
- If another body is added, the speed of light decreases (as always, of course only for an external observer from a space area with invariable gravitational potential).
- If one agrees that also the presence of energy increases a gravitational potential, thus photons of different energy content change the gravitational potential differently and thus also the local c. But this effect is purely academic and will play a role at most for gamma bursts etc..

Comment: Ref. to "Gravity exerts an attraction ..., but is not a force. On the falling body no acceleration acts (we are always weightless at the free fall  ...," I guess this describes the problem I have and had with accepting the equivalence of inertial and gravitational mass. "One mass" exerting impulse to some other mass does so NOT according to the mass it pushes. Feather and lead are not equal. Only the earth does not discriminate.   That's how I explain that you say gravitation is not a force. Textbooks that say there is no acceleration in  falling (or  the opposite) should elaborete even more.

Comment: I didn't say so, why? To the contrary, your daringly saying   gravitation is "no force" cannot be over-estimated. Gravity and gravitational mass are different from inertial mass; that's why they had to be "found" equivalent. If a "real" force" that obeys  F=1/2ma exerts force on a specific mass/object that object just does not determine, by its mass, how much force is exerted. Different! 1/2ma can not easily be used to "cancel" out m in Gm1m2/r2. - A couple of wavelenghts are a couple of different things, like small and big planets. Feather and hammer, what about Mercury and Mars flying.

Comment: Ref. to "The component of motion perpendicular to the center of force remains constant (in airless space)" in my understanding refers to "radial acceleration" (carroussel). Again, inertial (3 basic Newton laws) mass different from gravitational (Newton's law on gravitation)?   To me it comes to a a surprise to find that you are correct: different from attraction in a straight line which makes the gravitational force constantly change, with change of distance, this seems not to be true with circular motion (the attracting force (radial force)  is gravitation) as distance is not changed, is it?

Comment: Hi HF ("four"), please give notice to be removed to chat. I'm still working on your answer. Basically, I have a hard time accepting that all planets fall onto the sun  in "one speed" as I have F=ma heavy on my mind.  Conversely, Blue shift shouldn't be easy to accept as a fact as it seems to discriminate according to wavelenght. Same velocity of all objets and stars,   that recalls speed of light not discriminating wavelength. I must think it all  over. Thank you "!" - Perpendicularity seems the only curve that does not change the force by moving.