# Ultra-Relativistic and Non-Relativistic cases for energy of a particle

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, momentum, approximations

Let us suppose that we have a particle of energy $$E = (m^2c^4 + p^2c^2)^{1/2}$$

Can we say that for ultra-relativistic limit $p \rightarrow \infty$

$E = pc$ ?

Or in the non-relativistic case  $p \rightarrow 0$,

$E = mc^2$ ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned what you need this approximation for and why you're unsure whether what you propose is correct or not, since this would indicate to answerers what specifically they need to explain.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Its about cosmology. I was calculating the w in terms of the scale factor. And in the equation thers a term of $\frac{E_0}{E}$. So when I take the limit of the term (while p goes to 0 or $\infty$ ) I should make simpler the Energy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the non-relativistic case ($mc^2 \gg pc$)
you have simplified too much.

A better approximation would be
$$\begin{align}
E &= (m^2c^4 + p^2c^2)^{1/2} \\
 &= mc^2\left(1 + \frac{p^2c^2}{m^2c^4}\right)^{1/2} \\
 &= mc^2\left(1 + \frac{p^2}{m^2c^2}\right)^{1/2} \\
 &\approx mc^2\left(1 + \frac{p^2}{2m^2c^2}\right) \\
 &= mc^2 + \frac{p^2}{2m}.
\end{align}$$

Here you recognize $\frac{p^2}{2m}$ as the kinetic energy as known from Newtonian mechanics.

$mc^2$ is an additional constant (the rest energy)
which causes no deviation from the Newtonian equations of motion.

Comment: Surely, simplification is according to the needs of the user. If $p$ is negligibly small, it does you no good to lug it around in your calculation.

Comment: @Xerxes - the mechanics comes from change in energy, which - unless the rest mass is changing - comes entirely from the $\frac {p^2}{2m}$ and lower order terms. Thus situations where $mc^2$ is sufficient are very rare.

Comment: @PaulSinclair What is the energy available to a photon end state created by an electron and positron colliding at 25mph?

Comment: @Xerxes - I said rare, not non-existent.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a useful energy-momentum diagram (below).

A particle's 4-momentum is drawn, as well its $E$ and $p$ components in this frame.

When describing limits, it's good to explicitly specify
(in addition to what is being varied) **that which is being held constant**.

So, if you keep the [rest] mass $m$ fixed, 
then increasing $p$ means that $E$ increases in such a way to keep $E^2-(pc)^2=(mc^2)^2$ fixed---that is, up along the "mass shell" (the hyperbola [or generally hyperboloid]).

[image: energy momentum mass photon limit robphy]

It might be good to note that the components of the 4-momentum in this frame can be described by

$E=mc^2\cosh\theta$

and

$pc=mc^2\sinh\theta$

where $\theta$ is the Minkowski-angle (called the rapidity)
 
between the 4-momentum-vector and the vertical Energy axis.
So, $(v/c)=\tanh\theta$, 
$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\cosh\theta$, and
$\gamma v=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\sinh\theta$.

While keeping $m$ fixed, large $p$ corresponds to a large $\theta$.
Since 
$\cosh\theta=\frac{1}{2}(e^\theta+e^{-\theta}$)
and
$\sinh\theta=\frac{1}{2}(e^\theta-e^{-\theta}$),
as $\theta$ gets large, $e^{-\theta}$ gets small.
So, $\cosh\theta$ and $\sinh\theta$ approach each other---they approach $e^\theta/2$.
 
(In fact, it turns out that $\cosh\theta-\sinh\theta=e^{-\theta}$, and we said that $e^{-\theta}$ is getting small with larger $\theta$.)

[By the way, $e^\theta=\cosh\theta+\sinh\theta=\cosh\theta(1+\tanh\theta)=\gamma(1+(v/c))=\sqrt{\frac{1+(v/c)}{1-(v/c)}}$, the Doppler factor.]

[This image came from an old post of mine at [Relativity and Momentum of photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462660/relativity-and-momentum-of-photons) ]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes for both cases. Keep in mind that ultrarelativistic means an energy much larger than $mc^2 $.

Answer (score 0):

In the ultra-relativistic limit,$$E=(p^2c^2+m^2c^4)^{1/2}=pc\left(1+\frac{m^2c^2}{p^2}\right)^{1/2}\approx pc\left(1+\frac{m^2c^2}{2p^2}\right)=pc+\frac{m^2c^3}{2p}.$$If we neglect first-order corrections, we can describe this limit with $E\sim pc$, which means $\lim_{\frac{p}{mc}\to\infty}\frac{E}{pc}=1$. Similarly, the non-relativistic limit can be written as $E\sim mc^2$, meaning $\lim_{\frac{mc}{p}\to\infty}\frac{E}{mc^2}=1$.