# De Broglie Wavelength of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The De Broglie Wavelength is the very evidence of dual nature of particles ( specially photons). But if we use the equation lamda =h/mv, and then put the values of the rest mass of photon (=0) or the mass in motion (=1/0) , the equation becomes invalid.  Explain

Comment: Welcome to this site! Please consider that this is not a site, where people do your home work for you for free. In order to provide some focused help, you should show some efforts, e.g. tries how to solve the problem. Then it's easier to actually help you understand the concepts.

Comment: @engineer It doesn't really look like a homework question?

Comment: The "explain" at the end to me looks like a clear sign for an exam question or something similar. But of course, I might be wrong there.

Comment: It is policy here not to answer exam questions. I will downvote any such answer.

Comment: I have to say this doesn't look to me like a homework or exam question.

Comment: I think you should study, special relativity before asking the question, these questions are not base on Newton theories.

Comment: ...I agree with @John Rennie.

Comment: ...may be we must admit that not only massive objects but also moving packets of energy have momentum too ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de Broglie wavelength is not given by $\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$. It is given by $\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$, where $p$ is the momentum of the wave-particle.

The momentum of light isn't zero ([even though it's massless](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum)), so it has a finite de Broglie wavelength.

Comment: Ok. We know that light can be of different wavelengths.  Does it mean that all those different wavelengths have different momentum?

Comment: @JaydeepDas yes.

Comment: And does it mean that we can find the momentum of light by dividing planks constant by its wavelength (p=h/lambda)?

Comment: @JaydeepDas yes.

Answer (score -2):

The correct formula is lambda=h/p. For a photon p=gamma.m.v. your forgot gamma factor. P is not null for a photon even if mass is null due to the gamma factor. In maths this gives 0 times infinity. You can t say that this give zero

Comment: Y=root1-v^2/c^2

Comment: A lot of the confusion on this topic seems to arise from people assuming that p=mγvp=mγv should be the definition of momentum. It really isn't an appropriate definition of momentum, because in the case of m=0m=0 and v=cv=c, it gives an indeterminate form. The indeterminate form can, however, be evaluated as a limit in which mm approaches 0 and E=mγc2E=mγc2 is held fixed. The result is again p=E/cp=E/c.