# Energy when near the speed of light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, mass-energy

> An unknown particle with rest energy of $1 \text{ MeV}$ is traveling with a speed of $0.6c$ along the $x$-axis in our rest frame when it decays into two
>   photons, also travelling along the $x$-axis. What are the energies of the photons in $\text{MeV}$?

I've been trying to learn special relativity recently and came across this question, but all I really know is basic length contraction and time dilation. Would solving this use similar concepts and how should I go about it?

Comment: Length contraction and time dilation won't really help in this problem. As a first step [which will be refined later], how would you approach this using non-relativistic physics? What have you tried?

Comment: I think conservation of momentum would apply if thinking of non-relativistic physics, but since photons are massless I don't know how to approach the situation.

Comment: thinking in terms of four momentum vectors simplifies such problems http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply conservation of energy & momentum.

Based on your comment it seems the difficulty is that "photons are massless". They are indeed massless, but they can [still carry momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum). Once you know the momenta of the photons, it's easy to convert to energy via $E = pc$.

Comment: I see that momentum is equal to Planck's constant divided by the wavelength, but I do not know how to determine the wavelength. I know the photons travel at $c$, but I don't have their frequency to find wavelength.

Comment: @physicsaficionado there's also conservation of energy which you can use.

Comment: So if I use $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 +(pc)^2$ for the photons, it boils down to $E = pc$, but I do not have $p$. I don't know what else to do with the photons. As for the original particle, I have its rest energy, but also not its $E$ or $p$. I do not know where the original particle's speed belongs in this picture, but I think that's a key insight I am missing at the moment.

Comment: There are formulas for the initial massive particle’s energy and momentum in terms of its rest mass and velocity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#The_relativistic_energy-momentum_equation

Comment: I used these and got that the initial energy of the particle is $1.25mc^2$ and its initial momentum is $0.75mc^2$. I tried to relate this to the photons by setting that energy equal to $2pc$ because there are two photons, but now I am mixed up and do not know how to get the energy of the photons.

Comment: You are nearly there! The two photons do not have the same energy (in the lab). One goes forwards and one goes backwards. Their individual energies are the same as their momenta so, if your numbers are right, $p_1+p_2=1.25 mc$, $p_1-p_2=0.75 mc$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $m = 1 MeV/c^2$. Your calculation of the initial total energy of 1.25 MeV is correct. The initial momentum should be 0.75 MeV/c. You can now find 2 equations for the momenta of the 2 photons, one equation from conservation of energy, the other equation from conservation of momentum.

Note that energy is a positive scalar, but momentum is a vector. In this one dimensional problem, momentum can be positive or negative (or zero). So to calculate photon energy from momentum you need to use the *magnitude* of the momentum, that is $E=|p|c$.

In the rest frame of the initial particle, the momentum is obviously zero. So in that frame the sum of the photons' momenta must also be zero to conserve momentum.

Hopefully, you now have enough clues to solve this.