# Derivation of the momentum of light

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, momentum

Light has momentum given by $E = pc$, which is derived from $E^2 =(m_0c^2)^2+(pc)^2$, where $m_0$ is set to zero. However I thought in this equation $p$ is defined as $p=\gamma m_0v$, which means it would also be zero if there was no rest mass. It seems like $E=pc$ is a postulate that happens to be true but isn't backed up by theory. Is there a more rigorous derivation of light's momentum?

Edited out $\gamma$

Comment: $E^2 =(\gamma m_0c^2)^2+(pc)^2$ That equation is wrong. It should not have a $\gamma$.

Comment: *$p=\gamma m_0 v$, which means it would also be zero if there was no rest mass* No it wouldn’t, because $\gamma$ is infinite.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mechanics). First, write down correct formulas.

Comment: Relevant: [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum)

Comment: *isn't backed up by theory* When you are studying a century-old theory that is one of the foundations of physics, and something seems wrong, you should not assume that the theory is the problem.

Comment: That's my bad. I mixed it with the formula $E=m_0 \gamma c^2 $. When I said it seemed like it wasn't backed by theory, I meant every source I found that derives it out of the blue, where $p$ is defined to be equal to $E/c^2$ with no reasoning.

Comment: On the other hand the Poynting formula says that the momentum is $1/\mu_0 \bf E \times \bf B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relativistic momentum $p$ is the “spatial component of the particle 4-momentum”, whose magnitude reduces to $E/c$ for lightlike 4-momenta and $\gamma m v$ for timelike momenta.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how detailed for an explanation you are looking for, but maybe the following will be helpful.

The equation $p=\gamma m_0v$ is only valid for particles having mass. A photon thus has a momentum $p$ proportional to its wavelength $\lambda$

$$p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$

where $h$ is [Planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant). You might also know that a photon has an energy $E$ proportional to its frequency $f$ and thus proportional to its wavelength:

$$E=hf=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

(since $f\lambda=c$). It is thus easy to see that $$E=pc$$

If you are looking for a derivation why the above equations are true I'm afraid I can't help you – maybe someone else can answer in more detail.

Comment: This argument seems circular because I have seen $p = h/ \lambda$ derived using $E=pc$