# How do photons have energy despite having no mass?

Tags: visible-light, photons, mass

If the energy of the particles come from momentum, I thought mass is needed (as p=mv). How does light carry energy if it has no mass then? (e.g. how does light from the sun warm us?)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum

Answer (score 0):

Classically, light is a wave and waves can carry energy without having a mass.
Its energy depends on the frequency/ wavelength of the light.