# What is momentum exactly?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum, mass, definition

What is [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) exactly? I am confused that, is momentum a property of particle or something different.
Whenever i look for it's definition it is **product of mass and velocity of a particle**.
At another side, it is also said that a photon have momentum but rest mass is zero.
Then what is it exactly?

Comment: See also [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum)

Comment: Exactly, it is the cause root of my confusion that is momentum a form of energy or property of a wave also like a mass having particle