If light can't have relative speed, does it get left behind the earth imperceptibly?
I was just thinking about how if a planet is moving very quickly through space, everything we "throw" from it with mass would leave with a momentum from Earth, like a ball dropped in moving car, of course. But if light has only a constant speed, no relative speed, even when two beams travel in opposite directions, does that mean it gets "left behind", instantly falling backwards to our eyes if we were able to see it for a selected beam somehow? If we were traveling fast enough through space could we notice this, or do we already?

If light is emitted from a fast moving object it will still move at speed $c$ but it will be red or blue shifted, depending on whether the object moves away or towards you.

Maybe related/interesting to you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum

I really can't follow what you mean by "left behind" and "falling backwards to our eyes". What is leaving what behind? In vacuum, light travels at a constant speed of $c$ and constant velocity in all inertial frames. That's all.

everything we "throw" from it with mass would leave with a momentum from Earth.. according to who is this statement made? In a frame attached to earth they only have the momentum imparted by being "thrown" so to speak. According to the sun it will be that plus the momentum of earth and it's rotation. There isn't some absolute reference frame to speak of here, remember you are moving arbitrarily close to the speed of light in some other frame of reference.

Your question apparently is about Special Relativity, but is inappropriately tagged with General Relativity. In General Relativity the speed of light is not constant, but depends on the choice of coordinates and can vary from zero to infinity.

Light travels at the same speed in all reference frames. This fact is well supported by experiments (starting with the famous experiment of Michelson and Morley). Furthermore, consequences of this fact were deeply explored by Einstein. Therefore light most certainly is not "left behind" and it certainly does not end up "instantly falling backwards to our eyes". A good starting reference to aid in understanding of this might be Spacetime Physics by Edwin F. Taylor and John Archibald Wheeler.

Quite true. I shall edit this answer to better reflect the historical development.

When you drop a ball from a moving car, it has the same speed as the car. Then gravity pulls it downward.
You are right that it takes a piece of momentum with it. The total momentum before you drop the ball is $(m_{car} + m_{ball})v$. After you drop the ball, the car has momentum $m_{car}v$ and the ball $m_{ball}v$.
It gets more complex when you throw the ball. The before and after momentum is the same, but you transfer some of the car's momentum to the ball. If you throw it forward, the ball has velocity $v + v_{throw}$. The ball has momentum $m_{ball}(v + v_{throw})$ and the car has momentum $m_{car}v - m_{ball}v_{throw}$.
If you shine a flashlight forward from the car, the beam races forward at the speed of light. The car is left behind. You "throw" the beam forward. A little momentum is transferred from the car to the beam.
See this for more - How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?
